# SBT does not resolve jdt dependence

Tags: java, scala, gradle, sbt, eclipse-jdt

I have a project that use some component of the jdt.core library. The project must use both gradle and sbt for dependencies however, gradle resolve all the dependecies and SBT is not able to resolve jdt:

SBT:

```
name := "launcher"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.19.0-GA"
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.osgi" % "org.osgi.core" % "6.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jdt" % "core" % "3.12.2"
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test"

fork in run := true
```

GRADLE:

```
group 'name'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist
compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.19.0-GA'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

compile group: 'org.osgi', name: 'org.osgi.core', version: '6.0.0'

compile 'org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.12.2'

compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io',     version: '1.3.2'
}
```

As you can see the lybrary imported is the same. but SBT return this error:

```
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jdt#core;3.12.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.eclipse.jdt#core;3.12.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/ricky/.ivy2/local/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.12.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.12.2/core-3.12.2.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/ricky/.sbt/preloaded/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.12.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/ricky/.sbt/preloaded/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.12.2/core-3.12.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jdt#core;3.12.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.eclipse.jdt:core:3.12.2 (/Users/ricky/git/cs474/riccardo_pressiani_guido_muscioni_giovanni_agugini_bassi_hw3_4/launcher/build.sbt#L13-14)
[warn]        +- default:launcher_2.10:1.0-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.jdt#core;3.12.2: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1541)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1537)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$121.apply(Defaults.scala:1572)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$121.apply(Defaults.scala:1570)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1575)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1569)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1592)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1519)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1471)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.jdt#core;3.12.2: not found
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed Nov 12, 2017 3:46:52 PM
```

The trace gives an error at the point of resolving equinox dependecy. I have tried to look online but I did not find anything related.
I have also tried to import all the different version of the jdt and also tried to explicitely import the equinox library however that does not work.
It is not related to my code as that happen also with an empty project trying to import the right dependecies.

SBT-version: 0.13 and 1.0.1

The trace is reported only for sbt 0.13 but the same happens also with the newest one.

Comment: Libraries ain't the same: `"org.eclipse.jdt" % "core" % "3.12.2"` should be: `"org.eclipse.jdt" % "org.eclipse.jdt.core" % "3.12.2"`

Comment: same also with your modification, actually the same output of the question. @OriDar

Comment: Copied this snippet from maven central `libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jdt" % "org.eclipse.jdt.core" % "3.12.2"` . Which is same as I'd suggested above it seems

Comment: not working also with that @OriDar

Comment: you need to change the `compile 'org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.12.2'` to `compile group: 'org.eclipse.jdt', name: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core', version: '3.12.2'` more info https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.12.2

Comment: Gradle works I have problem in SBT @RameshMaharjan

Comment: but your error says that you have error with eclipse jdt core. isn't it so?

Comment: Yes but there error is given with sbt compile, gradle build works fine @RameshMaharjan

Comment: did you try what i commented?

Comment: What you have commented is written in gradle sintax, SBT is different if you look at maven central you will find the correct line for sbt